# Flex: browser popup rather than Alert.show() type popup?

Tags: apache-flex, popup, urlrequest

Im trying to create a browser popup window with some text, rather than using the Alert.show() or Flash Player level popups.

I have been looking around, and tried some stuff with URI Data Scheme, but thought one of you guys might have done something similar before.

**UPDATE: Answered Myself Below**

Comment: Does it have to be 'specified' in swf?  My approach would be to have all the code done in html/javascript and have Flex call a javascript function using ExternalInterface to open your window.

Comment: @J_A_X - yeah, have to specify it in the swf - thats all were editing at this point - updating the JS is not really an option. From what ive done so far from above, Im pretty sure it's doable - just not very JS savvy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does the trick:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.net.navigateToURL;

        private function urlJump():void{

            var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:NewWindow=window.open(''," +
                "'newWin','width=400,height=300,left=0,top=0,toolbar=No,location=No,scrollbars=No,status=No,resizable=No,fullscreen=No');  " +
                "NewWindow.focus();void(0); " +
                "NewWindow.document.write('hello');");

            navigateToURL(url, "_self" );

        }           
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button click="urlJump()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flex's externalInterface API to call javascript functions. and thus to trigger a new popup dialog.

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/External+Interface

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/09/calling-javascript-functions-from-your-flex-applications-using-the-externalinterface-api/

UPDATE:

```
var urlstr:String = "javascript:NewWindow=window.open('"+<any string> +"','newWin','width=400,height=300,left=0,top=0,toolbar=No,location=No,scrollbars=No,status=No,resizable=No,fullscreen=No');  NewWindow.focus();void(0);");

    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlstr);
```

Comment: thanks for that, but adding JS code to the html page isn't really an option - thats why im looking for a Flex only solution. Thanks anyhow

Comment: You dont' need to add JS code to html page. you can have JS code in your AS3/MXML itself.

Comment: Oh, yeah, updated my question - getting closer to what I want

Answer (score 0):

And you want the Flex window to stay open and just popup a new one right?  From what I remember, this is not possible with Flash since it needs to go through Javascript (window.open), however, you might be able to call it directly using ExternalInterface:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) 
{
   ExternalInterface.call("window.open", "http://www.adobe.com", "win", "height=200,width=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes");
}
```

As for the url, you can specify your own *or* use the uri data scheme and it should work.

Comment: Hey, put an answer I found in the question - works fine in Firefox, just need to test Chrome and IE now